# Symfony2 custom translation filenames

Tags: php, symfony, translation

Symfony2 requires translation filenames to be in the format **domain.locale.loader** (e.g. `messages.en_GB.po`).

In a legacy system I have files stored as `en_GB.po` so I'm wondering if there's a simple way to make Symfony load those files instead.

Comment: Can't you rename the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have your own loader and add the domain when loading the files:

Roughly it would be something like:

```
    $this->translator->addLoader('yaml', new \Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\YamlFileLoader());
    $this->translator->addResource('yaml', __DIR__.'/../../resources/translations/en_US.yml', 'en_US', 'addressing');
    $this->translator->addResource('yaml', __DIR__.'/../../resources/translations/es_ES.yml', 'es_ES', 'addressing');
```

You could load these on the boostrapping of your app, and have a service for it.

You can read more here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/custom_formats.html